# How to print out individual strings received from python list in ajax

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, google-app-engine

I send a list of strings to the ajax with

```
self.response.write.out(data)
```

where data is a list of strings.

I have ajax that receives the list and prints out the strings one by one

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/myurl",
            data: 'nb=' + url,
            success: function(data) {   
                var actual = data.split(",")

                 for (var i=0; i<actual.length; i++) {
                        $(".box").prepend(actual[i]);
                }
           }
 });
```

But instead of printing out each string, it prints out the entire list. What's wrong?

Comment: what is printed if you put following line in the success callback function? `console.log(data)`

Comment: the full list, like ["one", "two", "three"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can eventually read the `data` the way you are trying to do so, it is a bad idea to parse these kind of data yourself. A better idea would be to send the data in [`JSON`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) format and read it natively. Here is an example:

```
import json

...

self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
data = ["one", "two", "three"]
self.response.out.write(json.dumps(data))
```

and then your `$.ajax` call would look like this:

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/myurl",
    data: 'nb=' + url,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        // to make sure that it gets the data
        console.log(data);

        // to parse the data and do something with each item
        data.forEach(function(item) {
            $(".box").prepend(item);
          });
      }
  });
```